# Can ModelSim PE Student Edition co-simulate with MATLAB/Simulink?

Tags: fpga, matlab, modelsim, simulink

I successfully simulated my Verilog code in ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition. I want to incorporate MATLAB/Simulink in my simulations. However, I failed. I have this error in ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition:

> Warning: ModelSim Altera edition is not supported by HDL Verifier 
>   In hdlsim>l_ParseVsimVersion (line 1081)
>     In hdlsim/l_GetModelSimLibInfo (line 531)
>     In hdlsim (line 123)
>     In vsim (line 106)

It seems like the ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition is not compatible with MATLAB/Simulink. I downloaded ModelSim PE Student Edition and am wondering if it can do the cosimulations. If it cannot, do you guys have other ways to co-simulate without me getting the paid editions? TIA

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible, do you have vsimulink available as executable? It not, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already resolved the problem. ModelSim-Altera Starter Edition cannot be used for MATLAB/Simulink. It produces this error:

> **# ** Error: (vsim-FLI-3155) The FLI is not enabled in this version of ModelSim.**

I downloaded ModelSim PE Student Edition and it works fine. I use MATLAB R2015b 64-bit edition with ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.4a. Co-Simulation is good.